# Adjoint of Dirac operator

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

I understand that a Dirac operator (on say a closed manifold $M$ and a Clifford bundle $E$) is formally self-adjoint, in the sense that for $s,t$ compactly supported smooth sections of $E$, it satisfies

$$\langle Ds, t\rangle_{L^2(E)} = \langle s, Dt\rangle_{L^2(E)}.$$

My question: is $D$ still self-adjoint when viewed as a bounded operator between Sobolev spaces $H^2(M)\rightarrow H^0(M)$? My concern is that the adjoint of $D$ should be an operator from $H^0(M)\rightarrow H^2(M)$, but $D$ itself doesn't extend to a bounded operator between these two spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to say that a bounded linear map $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ between two different Hilbert spaces is self-adjoint because the adjoint of $T$ is a map $T^{*} \colon Y \rightarrow X$ so the statement $T = T^{*}$ has no meaning unless $X = Y$.

Comment: BTW, the Diract operator is a first order operator so you should ask about $H^1 \to H^0$ and not $H^2 \to H^0$ (which would be the appropriate signature of the (extension) of a second order operator such as the Laplacian).

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. Thanks :)